# Is there a way to activate colored output for Poetry in Windows Terminal?

Tags: powershell, python-poetry, windows-terminal

I am asking this question because I have not found an answer before.
I recently switched to Windows Terminal and some commands that the "Command Line" or "PowerShell" used to send me with syntax highlighting, are now sent to me without.

[image]

[image]

Example: on the left the Command Line and PowerShell opened via Windows Terminal, on the right without.

I don't think this is specifically due to the command I am running.

Is there a way to get back the same syntax highlighting as before?
If not, I am interested to know what can explain this difference?

I already tried to reboot my computer after the installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was reported here in poetry's GitHub repo: 
[No colors in Windows Terminal or cmd
#1972](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1972). A fix has since been made here: https://github.com/python-poetry/cleo/pull/313.

##### Old answer

At the time of this writing, poetry doesn't use ANSI escapes by default in the Windows Terminal, but you can force it to by passing the `--ansi` flag, or setting the `ANSICON` environment variable. This behaviour is due to a dependency that poetry uses called cleo, and the underlying issue is tracked in the corresponding GitHub repo: [cleo fails to detect ANSI support in Windows when run under a VT-native environment #104](https://github.com/python-poetry/cleo/issues/104).

If you're curious about things at a deeper level- how ANSI escape support can be enabled/disabled in a Windows console, see https://superuser.com/q/413073/1749748.

As [mentioned in the comments there by Yaekiou](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1972#issuecomment-1475318170), you can create an alias of poetry that adds the ansi flag by default, but I don't see why one would do that instead of just modifying the system environment variables or shell profile script to add the `ANSICON` variable.

Comment: Thanks, if someone need the command to set the `ANSICON` environment variable, here it is : <br/>
`setx ANSICON 1` <br/>
Personnaly, your last solution did not work for me, but thanks you very mutch for your excellent answer :)

Comment: @Alain What last solution? If you mean the last paragraph, that's not supposed to be a solution. That's bonus readings for you to learn how things work at a slightly deeper level.

Comment: Are we not supposed to change the registry key to `1` ? "the registry value may help enable ANSI for console-mode-oblivious apps"

Comment: ah. well if that doesn't work for you on its own, it's probably because without `--ansi` on some console/terminal environments like the Windows Terminal, ansi escape codes are not emitted _at all_. Setting the registry key cannot make something that is not emitting any ansi colour codes magically emit them.